# Symfony2 vendors and commit reset git

Tags: git, symfony

I have a problem on my vendors using Symfony2.3

When I began my project I added vendors to my git repo, now I'd like to remove it.

so I do:

```
git rm --cached -r vendor/
```

This command remove all my vendors from the git repo but I got problems, so I do a git reset to get my vendors back.

Now I have a problem I don't know really why, when I'l trying to run a command line via app/console I got this error message:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  The autoloader expected class "FOS\JsRoutingBundle\Command\Command\DumpCommand" to be     defined in file     "/Users/ant/Documents/projects/test/application/vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-    bundle/FOS/JsRoutingBundle/Command/Command/DumpCommand.php". The file was found but the class     was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

So I tryed to remove jsrouting-bundle from my composer.json but when I run

```
composer.phar update
```

jsrouting-bundle is not removed

So I'd like in a first time to remove manually jsrouting-bundle to re-download it.

And remove without problems the vendors from my git repo

Thanks for your help

Edit:

I solve the first part:

I went to verdor>composer>autoload_namespace.php and I remove this line:

```
'FOS\\JsRoutingBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle'),
```

I also remove the JsRoutingBundle from the vendor folder
and composer reinstall JsRoutingBundle.

But I'd like to have a tip to remove my vendor folder properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using composer, the vendor folder should only contain composer-installed data. Remove completely the folder from your disk and git, remove composer.lock, and reinstall everything using composer.json.

```
composer.phar install
```

You may have to remove vendor folder and composer.lock file on every copies on every hosts.